# Evaluating $\int\frac{\sin x}{\sin (x-a)\cdot \sin (x-b)}\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

$$\int\frac{\sin x}{\sin (x-a)\cdot \sin (x-b)}\,\mathrm dx$$

My try:

\begin{align}
&\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sin (b-a)}\int\frac{\sin \{(x-a)-(x-b)\}}{\sin (x-a)\cdot \sin (x-b)}\cdot\sin x\,\mathrm dx\\ =& \frac{1}{\sin (b-a)}\int \left\{\cot (x-b)-\cot (x-a)\right\}\cdot \sin x \,\mathrm dx
\end{align}

Now how can I proceed after that?

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex).

Comment: Sorry Lord_Farin , next time i will take care of it.

Comment: @experimentX Please do not bump questions with such minuscule edits of disputable quality.

Comment: You may start from $\sin(x)=\sin(x-a+a).$

Comment: **Step 1:** Open those $\sin(x-a)$ and $\sin(x-b)$ to write everything in terms of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$.

Comment: **Step 2** Use [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) substitution to turn it into the integral of a rational function.

Comment: **Step 3** Use [partial fraction decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Application_to_symbolic_integration) to integrate the rational function.

Comment: **Step 4** Return to the original variable.

Comment: **Step 5** Being in the 21st century don't do any of that by hand. Use user64494's answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$I_{a,b}(x)=\frac{1}{\sin(b-a)}\int\frac{\sin \left((x-a)-(x-b)\right)}{\sin (x-a)\cdot \sin (x-b)} \sin(x)\ dx$$
Angle-addition:
$$=\frac{1}{\sin (b-a)}\int \left(\cot (x-b)-\cot (x-a)\right)\cdot \sin (x) \, dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sin (b-a)}\left(\int \cot (x-b) \sin x \, dx -\int \cot (x-a) \sin (x) \, dx\right)$$
For the first integral, let $x=z+b$:
$$\int \cot(z)\sin(z+b)\,dz$$
Angle-addition:
$$=\int\cos(z)\cos(b)+\cos^2(z)/\sin(z)\sin(b)\,dz$$
$$=\sin(z)\cos(b)+\sin(b)\left(\cos(z)+\log\left(\sin\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)\right)-\log\left(\cos\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)\right)\right)C$$
$$\Rightarrow
\sin(x-b)\cos(b)+\sin(b)\left(\cos(b-x)+\log\left(\sin\left(\frac{x-b}{2}\right)\right)-\log\left(\cos\left(\frac{x-b}{2}\right)\right)\right)+C$$
The other side is similar.